# Numpy Refusing to flatten 2d array (flatten, ravel, reshape, index all fail)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I cannot make heads or tails of this.

I have a 2D numpy array that numpy refuses to flattened! I have tried 4 different methods to flatten it, and all of them fail.

`cluster_model` is a sklearn RadiusNeighborsClassifier.

```
cluster_model.fit(p_training_features, my_training_labels)
neighbor_graph = neighbor_graph.astype('?')
print(neighbor_graph.shape)
total_votes = neighbor_graph.sum(axis=0)
print(total_votes)
print(total_votes.shape)
total_votes = total_votes[0]
print(total_votes.shape)
total_votes = total_votes.flatten()
print(total_votes.shape)
total_votes = total_votes.ravel()
print(total_votes.shape)
total_votes = total_votes.reshape(-1,)
print(total_votes.shape)
flattened_total_votes = total_votes[0]
print(flattened_total_votes.shape)
```

And the output is...

```
(10000, 20000)
[[722 622 606 ...   0   2   0]]
(1, 20000)
(1, 20000)
(1, 20000)
(1, 20000)
(1, 20000)
(1, 20000)
```

When I print the matrix it comes out as dense... and I tried doing a conversion to dense, but it indicated an error because total_votes was already dense. I couldn't think of any other reason why the array was not flattening.

Comment: Is this thing a `numpy.matrix`? This is one of the reasons why you don't use `numpy.matrix`.

Comment: Hmm... okay.  neighbor_matrix is of type scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix and total votes is of type numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix. 

"don't use numpy.matrix" seems like an odd explanation... but it may be the only one.